# how to upgrade cloud function v1 to v2?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to try upgrading my v1 cloud function to v2.

originally, this is my function

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.post(...);

exports.functionName = functions.region("asia-southeast2").https.onRequest(app);
```

Now I'm upgrading it to v2. and since v2 function name cannot contain any uppercase, i change it into ["function-name"]

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions/v2";
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.post(...);

exports["function-name"] = functions.https.onRequest({region: "asia-southeast2"}, app);
```

when deploying, im receiving this error. I dont know what that's mean at all, it's very confusing.

> i  functions: creating Node.js 16 (2nd Gen) function
> on-function:function-name(asia-southeast2)... Could not create or
> update Cloud Run service function-name, Container Healthcheck failed.
> Revision 'function-name-00001-taz' is not ready and cannot serve
> traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the
> port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for
> this revision might contain more information.
>
> Logs URL:
> https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?xxxxxxxx
> For more troubleshooting guidance, see
> https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start

And opening the logs explorer from the said link, I get this message

```
Function 'function.name' is not defined in the provided module.
Did you specify the correct target function to execute?
Could not load the function, shutting down.
```

How could i upgrade my current v1 cloud function to v2?

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/2nd-gen-upgrade#update_imports) you should explicitly import each trigger as `2nd gen` SDK favors modular imports. Hence try imports as  `const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");`

Comment: @RoopaM I tried to change my import to explicit as shown in the document. But I still get the exact same error message.

Comment: Make sure `Cloud Run's` service agent have `roles/run.serviceAgent` role. Also can you share minimal reproducible steps?

Comment: hi @RoopaM for service agent, I think it is sufficient, since my current v1 function is running normally. For the minimal reproducible steps, which kind of additional information that I can provide to help you? For reproducing it, I think just publish a v1 function, with the camel case function name. then publish again with the v2 name without deleting the v1 function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced the exact issue following the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?gen=1st). First I successfully deployed `cloud function` `1st gen`. Later while trying to deploy `2nd gen` with a function name as ”function-name”, I faced the same issue. But I was able to successfully deploy a function with the name “functionname”or “function_name”. This could be due to bug in `firebase functions` using `hyphen(-)`. So I suggest you use names with either lowercase or underscore.

Example:

```
exports.function_name = functions.https.onRequest({region: "asia-southeast2"}, app);
Or 
exports.functionname = functions.https.onRequest({region: "asia-southeast2"}, app);
```

Also feel free to raise a bug in [public issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues)

Comment: thank you, I can successfully deploy my v2 function now. would not think that they also dont support 'hyphen' within the naming. this answer is really helpful, since I can use underscore